# Error YUI Property 'fn' of object #<Object> is not a function

Tags: yui

```
YUI().use('node', 'event', function (Y) {
Y.on('change', function(){alert("called");},'#searchForAgent');

});
```

I get this error message saying TypeError: Property 'fn' of object # is not a function

I am not sure why. Can anyone please help me, I have been banging my head as to what is the problem in this simple code

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using [`Y.delegate`](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/YUI.html#method_delegate) instead of [`Y.on`](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/YUI.html#method_on) in the case where the third argument is an element?

```
Y.on(type, fn, [context], [arg*])
```

The third argument of `on` is `context` and should be javascript `object`.

```
Y.delegate(type, fn, el,  filter, context, args)
```

The third argument of `delegate` is `el` and should be a CSS expr or a node, like `'#searchForAgent'`.